# Symfony2: how to call templating service in a formHandler?

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to do a contact form with Symfony 2 (version 2.4.1). My form is without an entity because it doesn't have to store informations in a database (just to send mails). I have a problem to call the templating render (or maybe renderView?) method for the mail template in the form handler class :

```
<?php
// src/Open/OpcBundle/Form/Handler/Handler.php

namespace Open\OpcBundle\Form\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;

class ContactHandler {
    protected $request;
    protected $form;
    protected $mailer;
    protected $templating;

public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, $mailer, EngineInterface $templating) {
  $this->form = $form;
  $this->request = $request;
  $this->mailer = $mailer;
  $this->templating = $templating;
}

public function process() {
   if ('POST' == $this->request->getMethod()) {
       $this->form->handleRequest($this->request);
       $data = $this->form->getData();
       $this->onSuccess($data);
       return true;
   }

   return false;
}

protected function onSuccess($data) {
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
               ->setContentType('text/html')
               ->setSubject($data['sujet'])
               ->setFrom($data['courriel'])
               ->setTo('me@gmail.com')
                ->setBody($this->templating->renderView('OpcOpenBundle:Opc:Mails/contact.html.twig',
                                           array('ip' => $request->getClientIp(),
                                           'nom' => $data['nom'],
                                           'msg' => $data['msg'])
                                          )
                         );

   $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

   $request->getSession()->getFlash()->add('success', 'Your email has been sent! Thanks!');

   return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('contact'));
}
}
```

This produce the following error:

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to Open\OpcBundle\Form\Handler\ContactHandler::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface, none given, called in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\sf2\src\Open\OpcBundle\Controller\OpcController.php on line 135 and defined in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\sf2\src\Open\OpcBundle\Form\Handler\ContactHandler.php line 18
```

So I tried to put the templating argument in the FormHandler call in the controller:

```
<?php
// src/Open/OpcBundle/Controller/OpcController.php

namespace Open\OpcBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Open\OpcBundle\Form\Type\ContactType;
use Open\OpcBundle\Form\Handler\ContactHandler;

class OpcController extends Controller {

   public function contactAction(Request $request) {      
       $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new ContactType());

       $request = $this->get('request');

       $formHandler = new ContactHandler($form, $request, $this->get('mailer'), $this->get('templating'));

       $process = $formHandler->process();

      if ($process) {
         $this->get('session')->setFlash('notice', 'Merci de nous avoir contacté, nous répondrons à vos questions dans les plus brefs délais.');
  }

  return $this->render("OpenOpcBundle:Opc:contact.html.twig",
        array("form" => $form->createView(),
                "hasError" => $request->getMethod() == 'POST' && !$form->isValid()
        )
  );
```

} // -- contactAction()
} // -- class

But this produce another error, no more $request:

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined variable: request in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\sf2\src\Open\OpcBundle\Form\Handler\ContactHandler.php line 43
```

Any idea ? Maybe I should use another method (more simple, without handler) to do my contact form with Symfony 2?

Comment: You are missing the `getForm` method.

Comment: And `$request = $this->getRequest();`

Comment: The `$request` is not missing. it is the only parameter of the action

Answer (score 0):

You should change those things:

- Replace `$request = $this->get('request');` with `$request = $this->getRequest();`
- Not sure, but I think you're also missing to use `getForm` method to your form.

[Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html) you can find requests information (seems that `getRequest()` is deprecated). And [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) you are forms information.

Comment: Thanks Manolo, it works. I had to replace in array('ip' => $request->getClientIp()) too. But is it documented somewhere ?

Comment: I've updated my answer adding information sources. Please, mark as answered if it has solved the issue.